# Pointer persistence in C?

Tags: c, pointers, scope

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int *ip;
    printf("%d\n", *ip);
    ip=NULL;

        if (1)
        {
            int i=300;
            printf("Inside If Block \n");
            ip=&i;
            printf("*ip=%d----------\n", *ip);
        }
    //printf("i=%d\n", i); /* Now this will cause an error, i has Block scope, fair enough */
    printf("*ip=%d\n", *ip);    
    return 0;
}
```

How come the last `printf()` returns the correct value of `i`?
 
Is it because the memory location still holds the value, even if `i` went out of scope?
How does it work ?

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, anything could happen. But what happened is indeed that the memory location wasn't overwritten, so `*ip` reads the old value.

Comment: Languages like C do not perform garbage collection. It is just fortune that the value wasn't overwritten by other code.

Comment: `How come the last printf returns the correct value of i` - You got lucky.

Comment: Yes, it is because its former memory location still happens to hold its last value.

Comment: I truly did :D.. That's what baffled me :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local variable `i` is out of scope, so cannot be accessed, but by chance its memory location on the stack, stored in `ip`, has not been overwritten. You absolutely cannot rely on this behaviour, but in practice you'll find it holds true on many platforms.

Comment: Undefined behavior ?? what does the C standard have to say about this ??

Comment: The C standard simply says that it's undefined behaviour and you cannot assume anything about the contents of `*ip` after the variable `i` has gone out of scope.

Comment: so this is something similar to accessing an array beyond its boundary.. we may end up with a segmentation fault or give it a miss..

Comment: Yes, exactly. Although with a simple automatic variable, it's more likely that you'll just end up reading a garbage value (if not the correct value) rather than getting a segfault.

Comment: @Bhargav: "Undefined behavior" means *pretty much anything* can happen, even appearing to work in certain situations.  But you're technically accessing memory you no longer control, and C won't make any guarantees about its value (or that the machine won't segfault or catch fire or something) at that point.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `ip` keeps the value it has, even if the variable it points to went out of existence.

You should take extremely care doing this, because in a constellation like

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int *ip;
    printf("%d\n", *ip);
    ip=NULL;

        if (1)
        {
            int i=300;
            printf("Inside If Block \n");
            ip=&i;
            printf("*ip=%d----------\n", *ip);
        }

    {
        float j=400.0;
    }

    //printf("i=%d\n", i); /* Now this will cause an error, i has Block scope, fair enough */
    printf("*ip=%d\n", *ip);    
    return 0;
}
```

the variables `i` and `j` might share their location as they never coexist. If `ip` points there, `j`'s value might become corrupted.